# How to update multiple document using mongoose and get their id's?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
    const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    itemType: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Item_Type",
    },
   inStore:{type:Boolean,default:true}
  },
  { timestamps: true  }
);
export default mongoose.model("Item", itemSchema);

const requestingTransactionSchema = mongoose.Schema(
requestedItems: [
          {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Item",
          },
        ],       
  },{timestamps:true},
);
export default mongoose.model("Requesting_Transaction", requestingTransactionSchema );
```

I have multiple items that are currently in store. Then there is a department that asks for x quantity of items from store. I wanted to find those items(based on quantity needed) then update the inStore field to false then get those updated items id and add it to the Requesting_Transaction document items field. Now the problem I'm facing is updating those items inStore field and getting the id's in a single query.

I have this code but I don't think its efficient.

```
let updatedItemsIds=[]
for (let j = 1; j <= quantity; j++) {
          const item = await ItemCollection.findOneAndUpdate({
            inStore: true,
          },{inStore: false});
        updatedItemsIds.push(item._id);
}

await RequestingTransactionCollection.create({requestedItems:updatedItemsIds});
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongodb-updatemany-method-db-collection-updatemany/#:~:text=MongoDB%20updateMany%20%28%29%20Method%20%E2%80%93%20db.Collection.updateMany%20%28%29%201,key%20in%20the%20filter%2Fselection%20criteria.%20More%20items...%20

Comment: This doesn't return the id's of the updated documents

Answer (score 0):

You need to see again your query, in findAndUpdate method you need to pass find condition and updating fields. where is your find condition?
if quantity is based on itemType and itemType's type is objectId, you need to use populate or aggregate function.

```
let updatedItemsIds=[]
for (let j = 1; j <= quantity; j++) {
      const item = await ItemCollection.findOneAndUpdate({match condition}, {$set: {isStore: false}})
```

}

Comment: I forgot to add the update statement when writing the question. I've edited it now. But still what I wanted was instead of running findOneAndUpdate for the amount of quantity needed (which could easily be 100 times) I wanted a single method that does the update (example update 100 items inStore field to false) and returns the id of the items that have been updated.

Comment: you can use find and save approach,at first you need to `model.find().limit(qty)` and loop through found item, update value and finally `item.save()`

Comment: Yet that is 100's (if quantity is in the hundreds that is) of save() calls to the db. Doesn't seem efficient

Comment: yes, but I think one solution else is to use mongodb aggregate, in aggregate you need to use $match, and $limit and at the end using $merge to persist your changes

Comment: Would that return the id's of the documents updated?

Comment: you need to test it to make sure, It has not happend yet to use this approach